# Java client-server sending file Streams

Tags: java, client, inputstream, server

Im trying to write a very simple client-server app where the client sends a textdocument .docx-format and server receives, simply.

My issue is that the file (mupp.docx) received is corrupted, according to word:
http://www.ladda-upp.se/files/2014/b126506.jpg

Im not sure where I do wrong here. The things Im unsure of are:

*Should the last reading, where fis.read(b) returns -1, be written to the file? To the outputstream by the client?

*Im flushing too often?

*I have an incorrect size of the byte[] b?

Ive tried moving around the if(x==-1)break; in both programs without success. I dont know whats wrong :/ Do you?

```
public class FileSender{
public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception{

    Socket clientSocket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",1234);
    System.out.println("connected");
    OutputStream out=clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("lupp.docx");

    int x=0;
    byte[] b = new byte[256];

    while(true){
        x=fis.read(b);
        if(x==-1)break;
        out.write(b);
        out.flush();

    }
    fis.close();
    out.close();
}
}
```

---

```
public class FileReceiver{
public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception{        
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket clientSocket=ss.accept();

    InputStream in=clientSocket.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("mupp.docx");

    int x=0;
    byte[] b = new byte[256];

    while(true){
        x=in.read(b);
        if(x==-1)break;
        fos.write(b);
        fos.flush();
    }
    in.close();
    fos.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change out.write(b) and fos.write(b) to fos.write(b, 0, x); That will resolve the error.

Comment: That's because we don't always read the whole buffer. x represent the number of bytes read.